# Error by initialState object passed to createSlice method of redux-toolkit: Objects are not valid as a React child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I am learning redux-toolkit. And I am unable to troubleshoot this error. Please help me.

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5bbg.png)

store

```js
import { createSlice, configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = { counter: 0, showCounter: true };

const counterSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'counter',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        increment (state) {
            state.counter++;
        },
        decrement (state) {
            state.counter--;
        },
        increase (state,action) {
            state.counter = state.counter+ action.payload;
        },
        toogleCounter (state) {
            state.showCounter = !state.showCounter;
        }
    }
});


const store = configureStore({
    reducer: { counter: counterSlice.reducer }
}); 

export const counterActions = counterSlice.actions;
export default store;
```

Counter.jsx

```
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { counterActions } from '../store';

import classes from './Counter.module.css';

const Counter = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const counter = useSelector(({ counter }) => counter);
  const incrementHandler = () => {
    dispatch(counterActions.increment());
  };
  const decrementHandler = () => {
    dispatch(counterActions.decrement());
  };
  const increaseHandler = () => {
    dispatch(counterActions.increase(10));
  };
  const toggleCounterHandler = () => {};

  return (
    <main className={classes.counter}>
      <h1>Redux Counter</h1>
      <div className={classes.value}>{counter}</div>
      <div>
        <button onClick={incrementHandler} >Increment</button>
        <button onClick={increaseHandler} >Increment by 10</button>
        <button onClick={decrementHandler} >Decrement</button>
      </div>
      <button onClick={toggleCounterHandler}>Toggle Counter</button>
    </main>
  );
};

export default Counter;
```

Here is my [sample-project](https://github.com/devakshay2/01-starting-project) on which I am working on.
This will reproduce the error on your machine.

I tried googling this error but it shows results not solving my problem.

Comment: Please [edit] the post to include a [mcve] where you are trying to render the object. Objects are not valid JSX.

Comment: @DrewReese I have given the link to the repo to reproduce the error. Only 2 files needed to be checked: store/index.js and counter.js

Comment: Links to repos are great supplementary material, but the relevant code you've an issue with should be self-contained in the post.

Answer (score 0):

`counter` is an object and objects are not valid JSX. If you just want to render the `state.counter.counter` value then access further into the selected state. Destructuring `counter` from `state.counter` should be sufficient.

`const { counter } = useSelector(({ counter }) => counter);`

Example:

```
const Counter = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { counter } = useSelector(({ counter }) => counter);

  const incrementHandler = () => {
    dispatch(counterActions.increment());
  };

  const decrementHandler = () => {
    dispatch(counterActions.decrement());
  };

  const increaseHandler = () => {
    dispatch(counterActions.increase(10));
  };

  const toggleCounterHandler = () => {};

  return (
    <main className={classes.counter}>
      <h1>Redux Counter</h1>
      <div className={classes.value}>{counter}</div>
      <div>
        <button onClick={incrementHandler} >Increment</button>
        <button onClick={increaseHandler} >Increment by 10</button>
        <button onClick={decrementHandler} >Decrement</button>
      </div>
      <button onClick={toggleCounterHandler}>Toggle Counter</button>
    </main>
  );
};
```